# Microdata from the German Census

Tags: data-request, germany, census

I am looking for open German census data at the micro or census block level. I am particularly interested in economic/health/educational outcomes. However, I cannot find any in English. Is this open data even available?

Comment: also check http://iab.de/ for econ microdata

Answer (score 2):

Access to microdata (and block level data) from the 2011 Census in Germany is subject to some restrictions.

Microdata is only available via an on-site access in a "Research Data Center". Access to the data costs 250 EUR and has to be for scientific purposes. You have to be affiliated with a "scientific institution", and this institution has to be registered with the Research Data Centers.

http://www.forschungsdatenzentrum.de/en/index.asp

There is one alternative. If you can live with results at the municipal level (or higher), you can retrieve some results via the online Census database.

https://ergebnisse.zensus2011.de/?locale=en

There is another alternative, if you do need individual data for research or teaching purposes. In that case the [German General Social Survey (ALLBUS)](http://www.gesis.org/en/allbus) might be of interest. It provides i.a. information on the topics you mention, and the data are readily available from [GESIS](http://www.gesis.org/). You only have to register and indicate what you are using the data for.